# The LINQ expression could not be translated - Entity Framework Core

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-core

I am trying to find all departments with more than five employees. This is what I tried:

```
public static string GetDepartmentsWithMoreThan5Employees(SoftUniContext context)
{
    var departments = context
        .Departments
        .Where(d => d.Employees.Count > 5)
        .Select(d => new
        {
            d.Name,
            ManagerFirstName = d.Manager.FirstName,
            ManagerLastName = d.Manager.LastName,
            Employees = d.Employees
                .Select(e => new
                {
                    e.FirstName,
                    e.LastName,
                    e.JobTitle
                })
                .OrderBy(e => e.FirstName)
                .ThenBy(e => e.LastName)
                .ToList()
        })
        .OrderBy(d => d.Employees.Count)
        .ThenBy(d => d.Name)
        .ToList();

    return "";
}
```

For some reason, this always results in an exception saying that the LINQ expression could not be translated. My assumption is that this is due to the ordering after the outer select. How can I fix it?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: have you tried _removing_ the ordering to _test_ your assumption and pinpoint the problem?

Comment: Yes, it's due to the ordering, but I don't see what's the problem.

Comment: And in particular, have you tried moving the ordering to *before* the `Select`? It doesn't look like that should alter the logical results, but it may just fix the problem.

Comment: @JonSkeet, thank you for the response! It works when I move the ordering to before the `Select`. Can you see my edit? Is this a good approach?

Comment: Hmmm do you really need to materialize (`.ToList()`) the sequence ? Especially the inner one

Comment: @Cid, what's the problem with it?

Comment: I am not sure when I am supposed to materialize and when not to. I am learning the EF Core right now.

Comment: Change all `Employees.Count` to `Employees.Count()`.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov, still the same exception.

Comment: I can't easily tell what you changed in your edit. But if moving the ordering before Select works, I'd suggest doing that.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

What is the type of `Employees` in the `Department` class?

This error can occur when `OrderBy` is used with a member of type `ICollection`.

Use `List` instead.

Comment: Thank you for the response! It's `ICollection<Employee>`.

Comment: Is this the problem?

Comment: Change the type of `Employees` to `List<Employee>` and see if it works.

Comment: After the edit: `ICollection<T>` is the recommended type for navigation properties. This answer is NOT correct. The question isn't clear to begin with because it lacks the excact exception message and it was changed in-between. It's not even clear if the currently presented query still throws this error.

Answer (score 1):

The current answer suggests that the navigation property `Department.Employees` should be of type `List`. That's not correct and it misses the point. The point here is almost the opposite.

First, `ICollection` is perfectly fine for navigation properties. It's used in many examples in the official Entity Framework documentation. Also, ordering by `Count` (without `()`) of such navigation properties works fine. And `Count()` as well, of course.

The exception message was something like:

> The query [query text] could not be translated. Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated, or switch to client evaluation explicitly by inserting a call to either AsEnumerable(), AsAsyncEnumerable(), ToList(), or ToListAsync().

An exception that's far too common at the moment with EF core 3, unfortunately.

The `ToList()` addition in the subquery is the culprit here. Removing it, and using `Count()` instead of `Count` to make it compile again will probably* make the exception go away:

```cs
var departments = context
    .Departments
    .Where(d => d.Employees.Count > 5) // Count or Count() is fine here
    .Select(d => new
    {
        d.Name,
        ManagerFirstName = d.Manager.FirstName,
        ManagerLastName = d.Manager.LastName,
        Employees = d.Employees
            .Select(e => new
            {
                e.FirstName,
                e.LastName,
                e.JobTitle
            })
            .OrderBy(e => e.FirstName)
            .ThenBy(e => e.LastName)
    })
    .OrderBy(d => d.Employees.Count()) // Here, the compile-time type of Employees
                                       // is IEnumerable<T>, so Count() must be used
    .ThenBy(d => d.Name)
    .ToList();
```

*I say "probably" because it works in a similar query I tested, but I don't know OP's class model.